# Combining 2 tables to produce 1 output - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query below, and it works.

```
$query_for_cat3 = "SELECT   sum,candidate_no,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM        (SELECT      SUM(score) / 5 SUM,candidate_no
          FROM        SCORE 
          WHERE category_no='$category_no1'
          GROUP BY    candidate_no
        ) a, ( SELECT @curRank := 0 ) r

ORDER BY    sum DESC,candidate_no DESC
LIMIT 5";
```

What I need to do is to combine this query to another table which is named candidates. It has columns candidate_no and candidate_name. I want to produce the candidate_name in respect to their corresponding candidate_no.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `JOIN` this with the other query on `candidate_no` will help you?

Comment: I tried JOIN, but it didn't work. I guess I don't know how to.

Comment: have a look at my answer. is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is something you looking for?

```
SELECT temp.candidate_no,
       C.candidatename,
       temp.[sum],
       temp.rank
FROM candidate C INNER JOIN
(SELECT   sum,candidate_no,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM        (SELECT      SUM(score) / 5 SUM,candidate_no
          FROM        SCORE 
          WHERE category_no='$category_no1'
          GROUP BY    candidate_no
        ) a, ( SELECT @curRank := 0 ) r

ORDER BY    sum DESC,candidate_no DESC
LIMIT 5) As temp

ON C.candidate_no=temp.candidate_no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join like this

```
SELECT 
    table1.field
    table2.field
FROM 
    table1
LEFT JOIN 
    table2
ON 
    table1.field=table2.field
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select data from two table then you need to have primary-key or foreign key Method in both table...like if Candidate_no is in one table as primary key other table as Foreign key..then using this you can access data as::

select * from table_name1 where candidate_no=(select candidate_no from table_name2 where name="Charn");